# Initialising MapFragment with GoogleMapOptions

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to use a google map with options such as disabling zoom gestures. I have added GoogleMapOptions in the code below, in the same way I've seen done in random pieces of source code online. The problem is it just doesn't work, I can set all the zoom controls to false but it doesn't seem to change my application when I run it.

```
private  GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
            options.zoomGesturesEnabled(false);

    MapFragment.newInstance(options);

       map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
            options.zoomGesturesEnabled(false);

    MapFragment.newInstance(options);

       map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

you can get the UISettings of the GoogleMap object and play with them according to your needs.
For example, if you want to disable the zoom gestures, you can simply add after the getMap() function:

```
map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
```

In the same way you can also disable the default zoom controls ("+" and "-" buttons to zoom in and zoom out):

```
map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

and manage the other typical GoogleMaps interactions (Compass control, Tilt, Scroll and Rotate interactions).

Moreover you can disable all in once with

```
map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Note that, if you have the map as Fragment in a ViewPager, with:
    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
you can let control the left and right scroll to the PagerAdapter instead of having them the effect of a scroll of the map.

Regards,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Follow the directions here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

My code looks like this:

```
    jGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();
    // jGoogleMap.getMyLocation();
    jGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    currentLatLng = new LatLng(jCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),
            jCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

    jGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng,
            15));

    jGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Current Location")
            .position(currentLatLng));
    jGoogleMap.setOptions( { draggable: false, zoomControl: false, 
        scrollwheel: false, disableDoubleClickZoom: true});
```

Comment: As far as I can tell my code follows those instructions. I tried moving the options code below the fragment manager code, but it had no effect.